# When using a fetch request, it’s always pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I check the status of the fetch request, I just see “pending”. Nothing comes back from the server. I presume that the issue comes from these lines:

```js
mews.insert(mew).then(createdMew => {
  res.json(createdMew);
});
```

But I did it exactly like the tutorial that I follow:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const cors = require('cors');
const monk = require('monk');
const db = monk('localhost/meower');
const mews = db.get('mews');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/style.css', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/style.css');
});
app.post('/mews', (req, res) => {
  if (isValidMew(req.body)) {
    const mew = {
        name: req.body.name.toString(),
        content: req.body.content.toString(),
        created: new Date()
      };

    mews.insert(mew).then(createdMew => {
      res.json(createdMew);
    });
  } else {
    res.status(422);
    res.json({
      message: 'name and content are require :('
    });
  }
});
http.listen(3000, () => console.log('running on 3000'));

function isValidMew(mew) {
  return mew.name && mew.name.toString().trim() != '' &&
    mew.content && mew.content.toString().trim() != '';
}
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const loadingElement = document.querySelector('.loading');
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/mews';

loadingElement.style.display = 'none';
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);
  const name = formData.get('name');
  const content = formData.get('content');
  const mew = {
      name,
      content
    };

  form.style.display = 'none';
  loadingElement.style.display = '';
  fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(mew),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(createdMew => {
    console.log(createdMew);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in server-side? Is the line `res.json(createdMew);` being executed?

Comment: there is no bug on the server side and no, res.json(...) is not executed. When I do the console.log of mews.insert(mew) I have a promise but .then() method not works on it :/

Comment: no one has an idea ?

Comment: You can try setting a `.catch` on the promise, to check if an error is occurring and somehow it is being hidden.

Comment: I did this :mews.insert(mew).catch(function(error){
            console.error(error);
        });  but the server console returns me nothing

Comment: if you console log at the top of `app.post('/mews'` does it reach?

Comment: I don't understand why you tell me to put it at the top of app.post ? :/ I don't think It will resolve the issue

Comment: A `console.log` won't solve the issue, indeed, but it will confirm (or not) that your problem lies in the server's business logic, and not in the client call to the server. Then we can focus on the part that fails. ;)